# Viewing DLNA servers' contents from Windows

Tags: windows, dlna

I have a Netgear ReadyNAS NV+ acting as a DLNA server.  I also have a WDTV Live box, plugged in to my TV, acting as a client.

The problem is that the WDTV isn't picking up on a couple of folders that I thought I'd told the system to take a look at.  So I'd like some way to 'see what it sees' and figure out whether the issue is on the NAS or WDTV end.  I can see the shares directly, obviously, so I know what *should* be there, but it's returning unexpected results when I access the various sections.

The only other device I have handy is a Windows 7 laptop, so presumably it will have to use that.

Are there any DLNA clients for Windows?  Ideally capable of handling photos amongst others, because the issue I'm running into is it's searching the music folder for the photos, instead of the photo folder. :S

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows Media Player is a DLNA client, that can play music, video and display photos.

In Library mode, look at the left side of the screen, and you should see your device under "Other Libraries". You an further filter down the content, by selecting the media type, either from the tree, or at the top screen navigation (the arrow next to "Library" will drop down).

If I may suggest adirection, I have a DLink NAS that's a DLNA server and I found that it tends to disregard certain folder names (especially those containing spaces, or with long names).

Comment: Thanks.  I'd seen a couple of things mentioning WMP, but couldn't figure out where they were referring to in the interface and assumed they must be lying :p

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wake up WMP, VLC can also access DNLA streams.

From the "View" menu (CTRL+L), you should see your DNLA server under the Local Network -> Universal Plug'n'Play heading