# Can I use a DLNA BluRay player as an external BD drive for my Windows 7 laptop?

Tags: windows-7, blu-ray, dlna, external-drive

I have a DLNA enabled Samsung BluRay player. It is connected to my home network and I am able to stream media from my Win 7 computer to the TV via the player.

However, I'd like to use this player as a BluRay drive to my PC. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks. Cheap, maybe, but yet another device in the house with double the functionality...

Comment: @Ramhound - I think I may not be clear enough here - I already own a BD player which can be used to stream media from my laptop to my TV (via DLNA). I can use it to play any BD movie (disc) on my TV. What I am looking for is a BD drive in order to plat BD media on my *laptop*. USB drive will certainly give my this ability, but I am trying to see if I can use my deck player as a (network) drive.

Comment: Well if the current device can stream to a tv, it can stream to your laptop, you just need a DLNA capatible player.  I would use VLC for a task like this.  http://superuser.com/questions/191736/how-do-i-connect-vlc-to-a-known-dlna-servern you are indeed right I wasn't aware you were currently able to stream content from the player to the tv.

Comment: @Ramhound -  A-ha; so this means that the player needs to be DLNA-server capable, or is this just implied for any such BD player, that can bridge between a PC and a TV?

Comment: Your current device is already a DLNA-server because your TV is able to have content streamed to it.  All you need is a client on your laptop, such as VLC, which has the same capability.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out. Does Windows Media Player have this capability (I have no particular problem using VLC, though, just curious)?

Comment: @Ramhound - BTW, why won't you make this a full answer, so I can rep you (and accept, once I check it)?

Comment: I don't have the capability to go through the process of writting a full documented answer, which provides screenshots, and detailed instructions. I have a single DLNA device on my network. Windows Media might be able to perform as a DLNA client, but VLC is the client of choice, for my personal network streaming requirements.  Here is some specific instructions for WMP with regard to DLNA http://superuser.com/questions/223654/viewing-dlna-servers-contents-from-windows

Comment: @Ramhound - ok, by "full" I did not mean "elaborate", but an "answer" rather than a "comment". Thanks for the links.

Comment: If I post an answer I only do so if I can document it, or if the question is simple enough, I post the information and the source.  I have neither for this answer, feel free, to post the answer yourself.  I don't have a DLNA server in order to test anything.

Comment: @Ramhound - Using VLC 2.0.5, I turned on the BD Player (Samsung F5700, w/ DLNA), had a BD movie in and opened the UPnP tab in VLC. I see my laptop in the list, but no sign for the player. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?